# Xamarin.Forms - UIKit Consistency error for iOS only

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a C# class file where I navigate to other pages, depending on the input. Since the interface is something different than a page, I have to invoke page navigation with InvokeOnMainThreadAsync. I did this with the following method:

```
public void Page_Navigation(Page navigationpage)
    {
        Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
        {
            if (navigationpage == null)
            {
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                var currentPage = Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
                await Navigation.PushAsync(navigationpage);
                Navigation.RemovePage(currentPage);
            }
        });
    }
```

I test everything on Android, but when I'm done I also test it on iOS just to be sure. On Android everything works, but on iOS I get the following error when I call with method:

UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.

That something like this occurs is one thing, but that it only happens on iOS is something else.
Does anyone know what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Best

EDIT

Calling the method looks like this:

[image]

Comment: When  did you call this method? Can you post more code?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Ok, Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here . I can't figure out what do you want to achieve with these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Microsoft for this and it turns out this is a problem in VS itself. I installed an updated version of my app on an IPhone with App Center and everything works just fine.